# Where can I advertise an open source project?

Tags: list, open-source, project

I have started an open source project and was wondering how I would best go about inviting people to work on the project. SourceForge is great but didn't fit the needs of the project. Any ideas?

Comment: What about SourceForge didn't fit your needs? Did you look at Google Code and CodePlex?

Comment: perhaps you could explain WHY sourceforge doesn't meet your needs, otherwise it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: Should the link be removed--to assure George that SO is *incorrect* answer to this question? :)

Comment: The source code management just wasn't what was needed. So I rolled my own in PHP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use Stack Overflow's Open Source Advertising:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010

Comment: where do those ads show up?

Comment: IIRC, on the sidebar of the main page.

Answer (score 10):

Announcing it on [FreshMeat](http://freshmeat.net) never hurts.

Answer (score 5):

You could start [tweeting](http://www.twitter.com) about it! Also, write about the project in [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com).

Answer (score 3):

[Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) might be something to look into

Answer (score 3):

You can also look forward to write articles about your project and post it on different websites like [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the project relates to a specific topic then there is usually a mailing list or set of webpages that relates to this. So, for example, if the project was primarily about XML you could announce it on [xml-dev](http://www.xml.org/xml-dev/). If about chemistry use the [blue-obelisk](http://blueobelisk.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page) mailing list, and so on. Mailing lists are a good way of attracting general interest which may increase your user base as well as your developer base.

Answer (score 1):

Throw it onto [Github](http://www.github.com)?