# Promoting Open Source Projects

Tags: open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I advertise an open source project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621916/where-can-i-advertise-an-open-source-project)

I'm going to be starting up an Open Source project which is an XML based forms (as in HTML forms) engine written in .NET and was wondering what advice people could give on promoting open source projects.

Answer (score 6):

Writing articles is a great way to promote your projects.  I personally promote my Open Source projects using [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com).  There are several others, but it's a good way to demonstrate the functionality of your project, illustrate why others would find it useful, and otherwise promote your hard work.

-Doug

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend to you to have a look at excellent book about that:

**[Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/)**

It is comprehensive book discussing about open source projects, how to get the most out of them and more.

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow offers free advertising to OS projects looking to build up a community:

- Here's the original announcement: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/
- And here's the most recent discussion of it: [Open Source Advertising - 1H 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362773/open-source-advertising-1h-2018)

Comment: Sounds interesting for me too, but I can't find info about this topic. Would you share a link, please?

Comment: But how? Please explain.